# Swift: Converting string to date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date as String but I want to convert it to Date.

The date in string looks like this - "2022-09-09T07:00:00.0000000".

***Code to convert it to Date:***

```
public static func dateStringToDate(dateString: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
}
```

No matter what I do, I keep getting nil as the output. I tried with ISO8601 template as well and got nil. I commented out line "setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate" but still got nil. Can't figure out what am I missing or doing wrong in the code.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [this](https://nsdateformatter.com/) is an excellent resource. I think what you are looking for is this:

```
func dateStringToDate(dateString: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS"
    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
}

dateStringToDate(dateString: "2022-09-09T07:00:00.0000000")
```

> Sep 9, 2022 at 7:00 AM

You have the year, then month, then day, then hour, minute, second, fractional seconds

Answer (score 1):

Use this Snippet of code

```
func dateStringToDate(dateString: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
}
```

You were not providing the proper date format